# how to split cells in phpExcel

Tags: codeigniter, phpexcel

Hi iam new to phpExcel and trying to export query results to excel.My current cell names are like ID,Person,Subject1,Subject2 (A1,B1,C1,D1).
Here each subjects consist of both mark and grade, i want to display mark & grade in excel for those subjects.That is cell division starts from C2.
Is there any idea?

```
  $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A1', 'ID');
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('B1', 'Person');
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('C1', 'Subject1');
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('D1', 'Subject2');





      $row=2;
     foreach($data->result() as $row);
     {
       $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A'.$row, $row->id);  
       $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('B'.$row, $row->name);  
       /*
         ??
      */
       $row++;
     }
```

Comment: correction please `$row=2;` and `as $row`. You used same name

Answer (score 1):

```
    Change your $row variable 



   $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A1', 'ID');
        $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('B1', 'Person');
        $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('C1', 'Subject1');
        $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('D1', 'Subject2');


          $count=2;
         foreach($data->result() as $row);
         {
           $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A'.$count, $row->id);  
           $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('B'.$count, $row->name);  
           /*
             ??
          */
           $count++;
         }
```